# fatal: unable to access CAfile. could not lock config file gitconfig

Tags: git, github, gitlab

When I am trying to pull from git I am getting error as:

> $ git pull
>       fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.ZZZ.com/S.A/Test-Practise.git/':error setting
>   certificate verify locations:
>       CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/path/to/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>       CApath: none

And when I am trying to do:

```
$ git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files\git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

Or:

```
$ git config --system http.sslverify false
```

I am getting error as:

> error: could not lock config file C:\Program
>   Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

Note: **I have tried re-installing git, running it as an administrator but still I am getting the same issue.**

Looking forward for help/suggestions.
Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

I guess your git.config has is owned by root and not by your user. Is your command working if you type `sudo` before?
This should change the owner of the .git directory to your username:

`sudo chown username -R .git`

Comment: Its not working if I add sudo, if am trying to run the code you have given in above comment am getting error as   **"bash: sudo: command not found"**

Comment: @Sultan Which OS are you using? You have to install sudo for your user to use it.

Comment: @Philj0 I am using Windows 10

Comment: @Sultan Ok, I'm not very familiar with Windows, but I quess you can run "runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd" to start a command shell as administrator. Then you can use the commands without sudo.